# What's causing this weird movement behavior in visual mode?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a plugin that involves moving up or down a variable number of lines. I want to create something that can be used as a custom motion, for use in normal, visual, and operator-pending modes.

Here's a little snippet of the idea: (the "3" here is for the example. The goal is to move a variable number of lines, but that's not relevant to what my question is.)

```
function! MoveDownThreeLines(mode)
    if a:mode == 'v'
        normal! gv
    endif

    if a:mode == 'o'
        normal! V3j
    else
        normal! 3j
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap w :call MoveDownThreeLines('n')<CR>
vnoremap w :call MoveDownThreeLines('v')<CR>
onoremap w :call MoveDownThreeLines('o')<CR>
```

The goal for this snippet is to create a custom motion that moves down three lines. I want the behavior of `w`, then, to be identical to that of `3j`. In normal mode, it moves down three lines like expected, and in operator-pending mode, the operator acts on four lines (the current and the three below) like expected. (Though I had to force the motion to be linewise using `V`, which is strange, because `j` is already a linewise motion. Does anyone know why that is?)

The problem is in visual mode. If I enter visual mode, then press `w`, the cursor moves down three lines, like expected. If I press `w` again, though, it only moves down two lines.

Similarly, if I enter visual mode and extend the selection downward in some other way, pressing `w` only moves down two lines. A strange other problem is if I enter visual mode and extend the selection upward, `w` changes my selection to be from the bottom of the old selection to two lines down. (The goal would be for `w` to move the top of the selection down three lines, just like if I used `3j`.)

How do I make `w` move down three lines in all cases?

PS: Ingo Karkat, if you happen to read this, thank you for your quite well-commented camelcasemotion script -- this takes some ideas from that.

Comment: It is a good practice to add `<c-u>` to clear out the visual range  '<,'>` part. `vnoremap w :<c-u>call MoveDownThreeLines('v')<CR>`

Comment: The `gv` is moving the cursor up a line on every execution except the first one.

Comment: @PeterRincker Right, I forgot about that! For anyone reading this later, it's not just good practice, it makes a difference in execution. And that's what was wrong here. Thanks for pointing that out! If you want to post that as an answer, I'll go an accept it.

Comment: I'm glad you've found my plugin helpful and well-commented (even though it's logic is rather complex). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prefix *all* (not just the visual mode one, as Peter Rincker commented) mappings with `<C-u>`, since you probably want to supply a `[count]` with your mappings (instead of the hard-coded 3).

In normal mode, a count (of e.g. 3) gets translated into `:.,+2` when `:` is pressed. Likewise, visual mode `:` prepends `:'<,'>`. The `:call` command executes the function **once for each line**, which typically is not what you want. (You can change that by appending the `range` keyword to the `:function` definition, but avoiding that the count gets translated into a range lets you use it even more flexibly; you can use it inside your function with `v:count`.)

Comment: Right, thanks. That makes sense. Is there a reason why you should prefix operator-pending mappings with `<C-u>`, though?

Comment: You don't need to, as an immediate count doesn't have the normal mode behavior, but I don't know whether that's a bug or intended. Better be consistent, as it surely doesn't hurt.